# OpenMDAO dependencies error with Microsoft MPI, and python mpi4py, petsc4py

Tags: python, mpi, openmdao

I have successfully installed OpenMDAO that I just found on GitHub. However, the ***Microsoft MPI*** does not appear, and the same goes for the ***mpi4py*** and ***petsc4py***, when all of these have supposedly been installed already...

I used the pip install commands for the python related dependencies, and the Microsoft MPI is within the environment variables as well. Has anyone experienced this before, or can perhaps guide a little? I would really appreciate it, as a computer newbie.

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the specifics of your install. In general getting MPI and petsc working on windows is extremely challenging. So much so, that it is not something that the developers have attempted. All MPI and petsc work is typically done on linux. You can see how the developers manage the install via [their testing scripts](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Broadly, you don't need MPI or petsc to run OpenMDAO, especially for just following the tutorials in the docs. You only need them IF you are going to run things in parallel. My guess is that you can carry on using OpenMDAO without those two optional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! It is valuable information. However, it would be advantageous to be able to use the parallel mode, as I plan on simulating and optimizing big study cases. Is it that difficult that the time saved in parallel mode would not be worth it either? Unfortunately I must do this on Windows itself, have you knowledge of any other links that show the process for Windows 10 by any chance?

Million Thanks! :-)